# Decryption of a 3-step cipher in Javascript leads to only half of the 26 characters in the alphabet being show, while some end up as symbols

Tags: javascript

So I have a project where I need to create a cipher which has 3 different types of ciphers built into it. In my case I have a Caesar cipher, Atbash cipher and ROT13. Whenever I try to decrypt a message however, some characters don't show up, while some show up as symbols.

Below is my code in Javascript

```
function decryptROT13() { 
    var dmsg = document.getElementById('message').value;
    var dnewMsg2 = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < dmsg.length; i++){
    var n = dmsg.charCodeAt(i)

    if(n == 32) {
        dnewMsg2 += String.fromCharCode(n);
    }

    else if(n - 13 > 90){
        dnewMsg2 += String.fromCharCode(n-13-26)
    }

    else{
        dnewMsg2 += String.fromCharCode(n - 13)
        }

    }
    decryptAtbash(dnewMsg2);
}

function decryptAtbash(dval) { 
    var dmsg = dval;
    var dnewMsg1 = '';
    var dtebahpla = 'ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA ';
    var dalphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ';     

    for (i = 0; i < dmsg.length; i++) {
        var dcodedLetter = dmsg.charAt(i);
        var dletterIndex = dalphabet.indexOf(dcodedLetter);
        dnewMsg1 += dalphabet.charAt(dletterIndex); 
        }
        
     decryptCaesar(dnewMsg1); 

}


function decryptCaesar(dval) {  
    var dnewMsg = '';
    var dmsg = dval;
    var dmsg1 = dmsg.toUpperCase();
    for(var i = 0; i < dmsg1.length; i++){
        var n = dmsg1.charCodeAt(i)

    if(n == 32) {
        dnewMsg += String.fromCharCode(n);
    }

    else if(n - 3 > 90){
        dnewMsg += String.fromCharCode(n - 3 - 26)
    }

    else{
        dnewMsg += String.fromCharCode(n - 3)
        }
    }
    dnewMsg.toUpperCase()
    document.getElementById('decryptedMessage').innerHTML = dnewMsg;
}
```

This what the output looks like:

[image: This what the output looks like]

Comment: When is `n - 3 > 90`?

Answer (score 1):

**character codes**

Our simple ciphers will work on capital letters A-Z and perform simple transformations of their ASCII character codes. We can go from a letter to a character code -

```js
console.log("A".charCodeAt(0)) // 65
console.log("B".charCodeAt(0)) // 66
console.log("C".charCodeAt(0)) // 67
console.log("Z".charCodeAt(0)) // 90
```

Or from a character code to a letter -

```js
console.log(String.fromCharCode(65)) // "A"
console.log(String.fromCharCode(66)) // "B"
console.log(String.fromCharCode(67)) // "C"
console.log(String.fromCharCode(90)) // "Z"
```

We will write reusable functions `toCode` and `fromCode` to simplify the rest of our program -

```js
const toCode = s =>
  s.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0)

const fromCode = n =>
  String.fromCharCode(n)
```

**cipher**

A `cipher` is an [isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism) - ie, it is a pair of functions whereby one function can reverse the effect of the other. Each cipher we write will have an `encode` and `decode` function -

```js
const cipher = (encode, decode) =>
  ({ encode, decode })
```

Character `A` starts at offset `65`, `Z` ends at `90`, and we don't want to apply our cipher to characters out of this range. Instead of handling this logic in *each* cipher, it would be nice if we could write our ciphers that work on a simple A-Z charset that goes from 0-25 -

```
(0,A) (1,B) (2,C) (3,D) (4,E)
(5,F) (6,G) (7,H) (8,I) (9,J)
(10,K) (11,L) (12,M) (13,N) (14,O)
(15,P) (16,Q) (17,R) (18,S) (19,T)
(20,U) (21,V) (22,W) (23,X) (24,Y)
(25,Z)
```

For any given `alg`orithm and character code `n`, we can  `filter` characters that are out of the 65-90 range, and automatically apply appropriate offset to the algorithm's response -

```js
const filter = alg => n =>
  n < 65 || n > 90      // if n is out or range
    ? n                 // simply return n
    : 65 + alg(n - 65)  // apply offset to alg's response
```

**atbash**

Now let's write our first cipher, `atbash` -

| atbash(n) | cipher |
| --- | --- |
| 25 - 0 = 25 | A → Z |
| 25 - 1 = 24 | B → Y |
| 25 - 2 = 23 | C → X |
| 25 - 23 = 2 | X → C |
| 25 - 24 = 1 | Y → B |
| 25 - 25 = 0 | Z → A |

The implementation is simple. As the table above reveals, the process to encode atbash is exactly the same as the decoding process. In other words, `atbash` is a pair of identical functions -

```js
const atbash =
  cipher(n => 25 - n, n => 25 - n)
```

**rot13**

Next we look at our second cipher, `rot13` -

| rot13(n) | cipher |
| --- | --- |
| rot13(0) | A → N |
| rot13(1) | B → O |
| rot13(2) | C → P |
| rot13(23) | X → K |
| rot13(24) | Y → L |
| rot13(25) | Z → M |

Rot13 *is* a Caesar shift of 13, so we can simply define it as

```js
const rot13 =
  caesar(13)
```

**caesar**

And lastly Caesar allows us shift the character code by a specified amount -

| caesar(shift,n) | cipher |
| --- | --- |
| caesar(-3,0) | A → X |
| caesar(-2,0) | A → Y |
| caesar(-1,0) | A → Z |
| caesar(0,0) | A → A |
| caesar(1,0) | A → B |
| caesar(2,0) | A → C |
| caesar(3,0) | A → D |
| caesar(-100,0) | A → E |
| caesar(100,0) | A → W |

We can implement `caesar` by parameterizing a `cipher` with a `shift` amount. `period` is used to perform basic modular arithmetic and support any positive or negative shift amount -

```js
const caesar = shift =>
  cipher
    ( n => period(26, n + shift) // plus shift for encode
    , n => period(26, n - shift) // minus shift for decode
    )

const period = (z, n) =>
  (z + n % z) % z
```

---

**encode and decode**

The ciphers we defined operate on character codes but we don't expect the user to do handle that conversion manually. We will provide a simple `encode` function to work with -

```js
encode(atbash, "A")  // "Z"
encode(atbash, "B")  // "Y"
encode(atbash, "C")  // "Z"

encode(caesar(1), "A") // "B"
encode(caesar(2), "A") // "C"
encode(caesar(3), "A") // "D"
```

As well as the reversing `decode` function -

```js
decode(atbash, "Z")  // "A"
decode(atbash, "Y")  // "B"
decode(atbash, "Z")  // "C"

decode(caesar(1), "B") // "A"
decode(caesar(2), "C") // "A"
decode(caesar(3), "D") // "A"
```

`encode` and `decode` accept a cipher, `c`, and an input string, `s` -

```js
const encode = (c, s) =>
  transform(c.encode, s)

const decode = (c, s) =>
  transform(c.decode, s)
```

The `transform` procedure is the same whether you are encoding or decoding. The only things that changes is the `alg`orithm being used -

```js
const transform = (alg, s) =>
  Array
    .from(s, composeL(toCode, filter(alg), fromCode))
    .join("")
```

**myCipher**

Finally we write `composeCipher` which allows you to construct your own complex `cipher` from a sequence of ciphers. The sequence of encoders runs from left-to-right using `composeL`. Naturally, the sequence of decoders runs in reverse from right-to-left using `composeR` -

```js
const composeCipher = (...ciphers) =>
  cipher
    ( composeL(...ciphers.map(c => c.encode)) // encode
    , composeR(...ciphers.map(c => c.decode)) // decode
    )

const myCipher =
  composeCipher(rot13, atbash, caesar(3))
```

```js
console.log(encode(myCipher, "DON'T CAUSE PANIC!"))
// MBC'W NPVXL APCHN!
```

```js
console.log(decode(myCipher, "MBC'W NPVXL APCHN!"))
// DON'T CAUSE PANIC!
```

**reusable functions**

Above we use `composeL` (left) and `composeR` (right) which are generic [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) procedures. These allow us to building a single function out of a sequence of input functions. You don't need to understand their implementation in order to use them -

```js
// func.js

const composeL = (...fs) =>
  x => fs.reduce((r, f) => f(r), x)

const composeR = (...fs) =>
  x => fs.reduceRight((r, f) => f(r), x)

// ...

export { composeL, composeR, ... }
```

**modules**

Like we did with the `func` module above, you should bundle your very own `cipher` module to keep your code nice and tidy. This also allows us to choose which parts of the module should be accessible to the user -

```js
// cipher.js

import { composeL, composeR } from "./func.js"

const atbash = ...
const caesar = ...
const cipher = ...
const compose = ...
const decode = ...
const encode = ...
const fromCode = ...
const rot13 = ...
const toCode = ...
const transform = ...

export { atbash, caesar, cipher, compose, decode, encode, rot13 }
```

When we write our program, we only import the parts we need -

```js
// main.js

import { compose, atbash, caesar, rot13 } from "./cipher.js"

const superSecret =
  compose(rot13, atbash, caesar(3))

console.log(encode(superSecret, "DON'T CAUSE PANIC!"))
console.log(decode(superSecret, "MBC'W NPVXL APCHN!"))
```

```
MBC'W NPVXL APCHN!
DON'T CAUSE PANIC!
```

**demo**

Expand the snippet below to verify the result in your own browser -

```js
// cipher.js
const fromCode = n => String.fromCharCode(n)
const toCode = s => s.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0)

const cipher = (encode, decode) =>
  ({ encode, decode })

const atbash =
  cipher(n => 25 - n, n => 25 - n)

const caesar = shift =>
  cipher
    ( n => period(26, n + shift)
    , n => period(26, n - shift)
    )

const rot13 =
  caesar(13)

const filter = alg => n =>
  n < 65 || n > 90
    ? n
    : 65 + alg(n - 65)

const period = (z, n) =>
  (z + n % z) % z

const transform = (f, s) =>
  Array
    .from(s, composeL(toCode, filter(f), fromCode))
    .join("")

const encode = (alg, s) =>
  transform(alg.encode, s)

const decode = (alg, s) =>
  transform(alg.decode, s)

const composeCipher = (...ciphers) =>
  cipher
    ( composeL(...ciphers.map(c => c.encode))
    , composeR(...ciphers.map(c => c.decode))
    )

// func.js
const composeL = (...fs) =>
  x => fs.reduce((r, f) => f(r), x)

const composeR = (...fs) =>
  x => fs.reduceRight((r, f) => f(r), x)

// main.js
const myCipher =
  composeCipher(rot13, atbash, caesar(3))

console.log(encode(myCipher, "DON'T CAUSE PANIC!"))
console.log(decode(myCipher, "MBC'W NPVXL APCHN!"))
```

```
MBC'W NPVXL APCHN!
DON'T CAUSE PANIC!
```

Comment: This is a fun kind of problem and I hope you enjoy seeing it solved using functional styles. If you have any questions, I am happy to assist.